# What difference between semantic and structural relationships?

Tags: oop, uml, associations

According to the UML specification and other valid resources, association is both a semantic relationship and a structural relationship.

There are questions:

- What is the semantic relationship?
- What is structural relationship?

---

Edit:
This question was closed due to a misunderstanding, but I did not receive a good answer to my question.
My question is about the structural and semantic **relationship**, not the meaning of these two words.

Comment: @Christophe Oh, I was not aware this had been asked before...

Comment: @qwerty_so no problem, with all the existing questions it’s inevitable. Anyway, on these kind if questions about basic concepts, a different perspective sometimes helps ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply look into a dictionary. (Here it's Oxford)

> **Semantic**
>
> relating to meaning in language or logic.
>
> **Structure**
>
> the arrangement of and relations between the parts or elements of
> something complex: flint is extremely hard, like diamond, which has a
> similar structure.
>
> - a building or other object constructed from
>   several parts. [...]

Structure is what you can see. E.g. you can see lots of bricks glued together. That's the structure. The semantics will be "house" (if it's that) or could be "art" as well as "ruin". So the semantics is what you interpret a structure to be.

Relationships are no different. You can see the connection between two classes. But what it means will be defined by semantics. You will need some context to determine it. Once you have that (requirements, explanatory SDs etc.) you're done.